# Do I need the Django "sites" framework to build a sitemap for a single-site django project?

Tags: django, documentation, sitemap

According to the Django [sitemap framework docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#installation), to be able to use the **sitemaps framework**, you need to:

> Make sure you’ve installed the sites framework.

However, the ["sites" framework docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/sites/#example-usage) say this about the "sites" framework:

> Use it if your single Django installation powers more than one site
> and you need to differentiate between those sites in some way.

The way I see it is that the two docs are contradicting each other. Sitemaps docs say "sites" should be used, and "sites" docs say to use "sites" only for multi-site projects. So, my question is do I need "sites" for my single-site project? By single-site I mean I have one single domain and I will not be having duplicated content.

Edit: I would like to add that I do have multiple apps in my django project. All the apps are part of one domain though. Does this mean I have multiple "sites"?

Comment: Hello, I am interested in the answer too :)

Comment: FWIW, `sitemap` seems to work without `sites`. I am in the same situation of only having one "site".

Answer (score -1):

You have one site, and only need one site. One site can have multiple apps, that is fine!

Django's documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/sites/) states that using django.sites in your INSTALLED_APPS is optional. In our case, we need it frequently for other apps and CMSes to work. You can use it even if you have just one site, that is okay!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/sitemaps/ states: Make sure you’ve installed the sites framework. So add it to your INSTALLED_APPS and you are good to go.

Good luck!